# Bitmap recycling and memory managment

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, android-canvas

In Activity-A, I am using the Surfaceview and the Bitmap as a background in it. When I go to onPause I release this and set it to null and made a explicit GC. It works fine. But When I come back to the same Activity-A  huge heap of nearly 3MB is allocated to decode the bitmap. This is because I am decoding the bitmap after the GC.

I am fine in recycling the bitmap and GC process. But I am worried that the heap allocation is getting increased so as to process the same bitmap.

When I move the next Activity, I need the save it in some place which should not hold any space in heap and when I come back I should go and pick the image. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Following is the existing code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSurfaceView.pause(); 
    Log.i("DragDrop", "In pause drag drop");  
        backGround.release(); 
        optionSelected.release(); 

        backgoundImage.recycle();  

        backgoundImage=null;
        backGround=optionSelected=null;

    if (tts != null) { 
        Log.i("DragDrop", "In pause drag drop stop");
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }  
    System.gc();

} 



    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      Log.i("Notice", "In run of mybringback"); 
        if(backgoundImage == null){ 
            try {
                Log.i("MyBringBack", "In run of mybringback"); 
                backgoundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getAssetImage(getApplicationContext(),"backgroundhomepage"), (int) dWidth, (int) dHeight, true);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ourHolder = getHolder();
        while (isRunning) {
//          Log.i("DragDrop", "ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()" +  ourHolder.getSurface().isValid() );
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            } 
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();    
            screenCenterX = dWidth / 2;
            screenCenterY = dHeight / 2; 
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0, null);   
            if (imagePublishDone) {
                if(!welcomeDone){ 
                    message = "Drop your wish to panda";
                    tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    welcomeDone=true;
                }
                moveImageInEllipticalPath();
            } else {
                initialImagePublish();
            }

            centreReached = false;
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    } 


    public  Bitmap getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assets = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream buffer = null;
        try {
            buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];   
        options.inPurgeable = true; 
        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, options);
        Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, (int) dWidth, (int) dHeight, true);
        temp.recycle();
        temp=null; 
        return finalImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution to your problem would be simply using the [`inPurgeable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPurgeable) flag when decoding the `Bitmap`.

That way when the system needs to reclaim memory, it will internally "recycle" the bitmap but when the bitmap needs to be displayed again it will automatically load it in.

[EDIT]

There are several problems with the code you have.

1. The `inTempStorage` in your `getAssetImage(...)` is useless. This "optimization" is supposed to provide the decoder with memory that it would need for temporary calculations. If you don't provide it, the decoder will simply allocate it by itself. This is only an optimization if you amortize the cost of that allocation over multiple decodes. However, your solution does the allocation every time. Might as well let the decoder do that since it will know exactly how much memory it will need.
2. It seems like you're wasting A LOT of memory on scaling your bitmaps. `getAssetImage(...)` decodes a full size image which is then scaled, returned, and scaled again. That is a lot of extra work and memory. You should consider sampling the image via [`inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize). To figure out the proper sampling factor you can use [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds).
3. Finally, your use of `inPurgeable` is incorrect. The system will only be able to purge the bitmap decoded with that option. However, as mentioned above, you go ahead and create new bitmaps after loading in the purgeable one. Furthermore, even if you fix your design so that you only load in the correct bitmap, I don't think the system will be able to reload it for you because you use `decodeStream(...)`. Streams cannot be reopened and rewound in a generic way so the system will not be able to reread that data. Try decoding from a file instead. You can also play with [inInputShareable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inInputShareable) for more control over the purging behavior.